# Ansible: Read a single value with key from YAML file

Tags: ansible

I have a yaml file with content like

```
abc: 123
def: 456
ddd: {{ eee }}
xyz: 789
```

I try to avoid to load the whole file into vars space, but I need value of 'def' in my playbook. I thought I could use lookup to resolve the problem. But after

```
lookup('file', 'path/to/file.yaml')
```

I don't know how to parse the content of file with Ansible to get a value with its key.
I tried include_vars, but that one forced me to modify yaml file value like that {{ eee }} to "{{ eee }}", which modified the actual value.
Is there a simple way to just read YAML file key values?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**update**

Given the file

```yaml
shell> cat /tmp/file.yaml 
abc: 123
def: 456
ddd: {{ eee }}
xyz: 789
```

and the variable

```yaml
eee: 999
```

the lookup plugin *file*

```yaml
  d1: "{{ lookup('file', '/tmp/file.yaml') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  d1: |-
    abc: 123
    def: 456
    ddd: {{ eee }}
    xyz: 789
```

You have to use the lookup plugin *template* to expand the [Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#) template

```yaml
  d1: "{{ lookup('template', '/tmp/file.yaml') }}"
```

gives the literal [block](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#chapter-8-block-style-productions)

```yaml
  d1: |-
    abc: 123
    def: 456
    ddd: 999
    xyz: 789
```

Use the filter *from_yaml* to convert it to YAML

```yaml
  d1: "{{ lookup('template', '/tmp/file.yaml')|from_yaml }}"
```

gives the YAML dictionary

```yaml
  d1:
    abc: 123
    ddd: 999
    def: 456
    xyz: 789
```

Declare variables if you want to

```yaml
  _def: "{{ d1.def }}"
  _ddd: "{{ d1.ddd }}"
```

and display the results

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |

          def: {{ _def }}
          ddd: {{ _ddd }}
          def: {{ _def|type_debug }}
          ddd: {{ _ddd|type_debug }}

          d1.def: {{ d1.def }}
          d1.ddd: {{ d1.ddd }}
          d1.def: {{ d1.def|type_debug }}
          d1.ddd: {{ d1.ddd|type_debug }}
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: |-

    def: 456
    ddd: 999
    def: str
    ddd: str

    d1.def: 456
    d1.ddd: 999
    d1.def: int
    d1.ddd: int
```

You can see that the attributes are integers but the variables are strings. This is because the expansion must be quoted. If you want to `preserve variable types during template operations` set [DEFAULT_JINJA2_NATIVE](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-jinja2-native) to `True`

Then, you get

```yaml
  msg: |-

    def: 456
    ddd: 999
    def: int
    ddd: int
  
    d1.def: 456
    d1.ddd: 999
    d1.def: int
    d1.ddd: int
```

---

**origin**

Use *template* to read the file, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        _def: "{{ (lookup('template', 'path/to/file.yaml')|from_yaml).def }}"
      vars:
        eee: 'default'
```

gives

```yaml
  _def: '456'
```

The variable *eee* must be defined. See the [thread](https://groups.google.com/g/ansible-project/c/ZandDKBT_1s/m/_NrLxxnrAwAJ).

---

Probably, you might want to set a dictionary first, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        d1: "{{ lookup('template', 'path/to/file.yaml')|from_yaml }}"
      vars:
        eee: 'default'
    - set_fact:
        _def: d1.def
```